# OData result base url

Tags: odata

I am requesting OData service like this,

```
https://www.example.com/part1/part2/_vti_bin/myServiceFolder/MyOdataService.svc
```

but when it returns   xml back...

I am getting this,

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed
 xml:base=https://www.example.com/_vti_bin/myServiceFolder/MyOdataService.svc
```

What could had caused it ? I am hosting this service in SharePoint web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peter_qian/2010/03/23/overwriting-the-service-root-uri-in-wcf-data-service/

Basically it was using host's name or url and constructing response, so I had to overwrite following according to my needs,

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["MicrosoftDataServicesRootUri"] = serviceUri;

OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["MicrosoftDataServicesRequestUri"] = requestUri;
```